# Javascript validation to allow valid domains

Tags: javascript, validation, ecmascript-6

Looking for a way to validate the entered domain are correct

1. Check for items in array to see valid domain name
2. Correct typos and suggest right in came of typo found for eg if someone types june@gamil.com output should be **Do you mean june@gmail.com**

```
    function checkForDomainTypo(userEmail) {
      // validate following domain also allow private domain i.e. email@abc.com , email@def.com are valid too
      const domains = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail', 'outlook', 'yahoo', 'icloud', 'mail', 'zoho'];
      // note gmail can only have .com as thats the only one available whereas yahoo can have yahoo.com as well as yahoo.co.uk
      const [leftPart, rightPart] = userEmail.split('@');
      // Looking to find typos like gamil.com, gmaill.com, gmal.com, yaho.com,  and suggest correct email address

      var reg = /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/
      if (reg.test(email)){
      }

    }
```

Valid email address

1. first.last@example.com
2. yourname.aaa@gmail.com
3. yourname@yahoo.co.in

Invalid Email example

1. yourname@gamil.com (typo)
2. yourname@gmail.co (incorrect Top level domain)
3. yourname@yaho.com (incorrect yahoo address)

Use case of this issue is pretty straightforward to detect incorrect known domain names. I tried searching for available solution but found none.

Comment: well, all examples so far are questionable: `co` is a valid TLD and I'm positive both `gamil.com` and `yaho.com` do exist. Unless you have an extensive whitelist of approved domains, this sounds like an impossible thing to do.

Comment: gmail.co isn't a valid TLD as far as I know... and this restriction i.e. only allow. com is for gmail only

Comment: before you try and reinvent the wheel, have you checked out if there is a reputable npm package for this?

Comment: I didnt found any package